# How does Rudin get $3^k$ in his proof of the Covering Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis

In his book *Real & Complex Analysis* p. 137, Rudin gives a proof of the Covering Lemma (Lemma 7.3).  The lemma is given as

> If $W$ is the union of a finite collection of balls $B(x_i, r_i)$, $1 \leq i \leq N$ then there is a set $S \subset \{1, \ldots, N \}$ so that
>
> (a) the balls $B(x_i, r_i)$ with $i \in S$ are disjoint,
>
> (b) $W \subset \bigcup_{i \in S} B(x_i, 3r_i)$, and
>
> (c) $m(W) \leq 3^k \sum_{i \in S} m(B(x_i, r_i))$.

I'm curious as to how he is obtaining the bound as $3$ times the radius.  In the proof given in the book he just says

> Every discarded $B_j$ is a subset of $B(x_i, 3r_i)$ for some $i \in S$, for if $r' \leq r$ and $B(x', r')$ intersects $B(x,r)$, then $B(x', r') \subset B(x, 3r)$.

I can't seem to figure out where the $3$ is coming from.  Of course, it isn't critical... I can establish the same thing for a larger constant, which is all that we need, but I would like to figure out how he is getting this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B(x_1,r_1) \cap B(x_2,r_2)$ is nonempty and $r_1\leq r_2$, then $B(x_1,r_1) \subseteq B(x_2,3r_2)$. Indeed, if $y \in B$, $|y-x_1|<r_1$. In addition, there exists $z \in B(x_1,r_1) \cap B(x_2,r_2)$ so $|z-x_1|<r_1$ and $|z-x_2|<r_2$. Thus
$$|y-x_2| \leq |y-x_1|+|x_1-z|+|z-x_2| < r_1+r_2+r_2<3r_2.$$
The idea is that you can find a disjoint collection of balls so that if you blew each one up by a factor of 3, you'd still cover all of $W$. This is because every ball $B$ that was discarded intersected a ball $B(x,r)$ that was kept, so by the above $B$ is contained in $B(x,3r)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the extended triangle inequality: let $y \in B(x',r')$, $z \in B(x',r') \cap B(x,r)$. Then, $$d(x,y') \leq d(y',x') + d(x,z) + d(x',z) \leq r' + r + r' \leq 3r$$
and the claim follows.